# How to solve this mixed problem using separating variables in PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, hyperbolic-equations

On $\{0<x<1,t>0\}$ I want to solve this mixed problem:

$\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  {u_{tt}} - {u_{xx}} = 0 \\ 
  u(0,t) = 0,{u_x}(1,t) = \frac{{\sin t}}{{2017}} \\ 
  u(x,0) = 0,{u_t}(x,0) = 0 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$

It's obvious that I should use separating variables, but I find it hard to determine the eigenvalues... Could anyone show me a solution as an example for problems of this type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that there can't be any eigenvalues if your BCs are homogeneous, because if you have an eigenfunction then a multiple of it should be an eigenfunction, but a multiple of a function satisfying your BCs will never satisfy your BCs. So you need to move the inhomogeneity from the BCs to somewhere else. The given answer shows a way to do this (though I think there are some small errors in it...)

Comment: Typo: the first usage of the word "homogeneous" in my comment should have been *inhomogeneous*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a substitution of the form
$$
            u(x,t)=v(x,t)+a(x)\frac{\sin t}{2017}.
$$
The condition $u(0,t)=0$ becomes $v(0,t)=0$ if $a(0)=0$.
The condition $u_{x}(1,t)=\sin t/2017$ becomes $v_{x}(1,t)=0$ if $a'(1)=1$. And the equation $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0$ becomes $v_{tt}-v_{xx}=0$ if
$$
        a(x)+a''(x)=0.
$$
So you want a solution $a(x)$ of
$$
                 a''(x)+a(x) = 0,\;\; a(0)=0,\; a'(1)=1.
$$
That leads to $a(x)=\sin(x)/\cos(1)$. Everything works out to give a new equation for $v$ of the form:
$$
            v_{tt}-v_{xx} = 0 \\
            v(0,t)=0, \;\;
            v_{x}(1,t)=0 \\
            v(x,0)=0,\;\; v_{t}(x,0)=-\frac{\sin(x)}{2017\cos(1)}.
$$
This looks like a standard problem now. After solving for $v$, the original solution is
$$
        u(x,t) = v(x,t) + \frac{\sin x}{\cos 1}\frac{\sin t}{2017}.
$$

Comment: Did you make a sign error at some point? I'm a bit surprised to see the Laplace equation emerge from a given wave equation.

Comment: @Ian : That was a typo that snowballed. I think I have that fixed now.